# Cordova-icon gives error on run

Tags: cordova, icons

I am using cordova-icon to generate all my icon files. I get this error when I run cordova-icon:

Checking Project & Icon

√  platforms found: android
  √  icon.png exists
  √  config.xml exists

Generating Icons for android

{ [Error: Command failed: Invalid Parameter - -set
] timedOut: false, killed: false, code: 4, signal: null }

I am running this on Windows

Any idea how to resolve this?

https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-icon

Comment: You should accept the answer below, it is working great, and not only for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution. ImageMagick needed to be installed for Windows. I used this download and it worked after restarting my command prompt.

[Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

Comment: Thanks, got the same error and it seems you have to read the page  to find out it has dependencies :)

Comment: Ha ha ya, I found the solution and asked the creator to put in the readme for others

Comment: Do not forget to select legacy utils checkbox on Windows!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use other services that do not require anything to install.

See [makeappicon.com](http://makeappicon.com)